# Difference between accessing non-existent array index and existing-but-empty index

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I wrote

```
vector<int> example(5);
example[6];
```

What difference would it make with the following?

```
vector<int> example(6);
example[5];
```

In the first case I'm  trying to access a non-existent, non-declared index. Could that result in malicious code execution? Would it be possible to put some sort of code in the portion on memory corresponding to `example[5]` and have it executed by a program written like the first above?

What about the second case? Would it still be possible to place code in the area of memory of `example[5]`, even though it should be reserved to my program, even if I haven't written anything in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case reaches beyond the vector's buffer and thus invokes Undefined Behaviour. Technically, this means literally *anything* can happen. But it's unlikely to be directly exploitable to run malicious code—either the program will try to read the invalid memory (getting a garbage value or a memory error), or the compiler has eliminated the code path altogether (because it's allowed to assume UB doesn't happen). Depending on what's done with the result, it might potentially *reveal* unintended data from memory, though.

In the second case, all is well. Your program *has* already written into this memory—it has value-initialised all the 6 `int` objects in the vector (which happens in `std::vector`'s constructor). So you're guarnateed to find a `0` of type `int` there.

Answer (score 2):

> Could that result in malicious code execution?

No, this causes 'only' undefined behaviour.
Simple code execution exploits usually **write** past the end of a stack-allocated buffer, thereby overwriting a return adress. When the function returns, it jumps to the malicious code. A write is always required, because else there is no malicious code in your program's address space.

With a `vector` the chances that this happens are low, because the storage for the elements is not allocated on the stack.
By writing to a wrong location on the heap, exploits are possible too, but they are much more complicated.